# When converting .dat into csv my code change the output values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a .dat file and I am trying to convert it into a csv one.
I have found a piece of code that "somehow" solved my problem.
The thing is: such code gave me a messed up output file as a result. In other words: it changed my values!!!!

Someone can help me with that?
I am a total beginner at this.

Thanks a lot.

```
with open('f.dat') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    newLines = []
    for line in lines:
        newLines.append(newLine)

with open('f_out.csv','w') as output_file:
    file_writer = csv.writer(output_file)
    file_writer.writerows(newLines)
```

My input file looks like this:

```
"-18.7723311308 3166157043.25795    0   1006743187.3562
-18.8214122765  188717303.231381    0   57141624.5127759
-18.7022205742  399933910.540253    0   87142384.8698447
-18.5903166748  23045528.3797531    0   5841919.83133624
-18.3051499783  76457482.0309581    0   25326122.2381197"
(with more lines)
```

And the output file like this:

```
-21.5607314306,1200000000.0,0,500000000.0,MBH
-21.5607314306,1200000000.0,0,500000000.0,MBH
-21.5607314306,1200000000.0,0,500000000.0,MBH
```

What I simply want is an output file where my columns are separated by a comma, like:

```
"-18.7723311308, 3166157043.25795, 0, 1006743187.3562
-18.8214122765, 188717303.231381, 0 ,57141624.5127759"
```

Answer (score 0):

.dat files are not much readable using file io operations
you can use asammdf module to read the .dat file.use
pip install asammdf

Answer (score 0):

There is a module called pandas which can convert a list to csv file easily. Try this code it works.

```
import pandas as pd
with open('f.dat') as input_file:
    lines = input_file.readlines()
    newLines = []
    for line in lines:
        newLines.append(line)
pd.DataFrame(newLines).to_csv('f_out.csv')
```

Comment: Now I am getting this error: 
NameError: name 'newLine' is not defined. is it because I am using python 3?

Comment: There was a variable newLine in your code which should be line

Answer (score 0):

> .dat files are not much readable using file io operations you can use asammdf module to read the .dat file.use pip install asammdf

.dat files in the context of *asammdf* are Measurement Data File v2 or v3 typically used in the automotive domain. I don't think the OP has this kind of file